# Center anchor point for a collapsed Pre-comp

Tags: expression, after-effects

I have a problem with a comp that contains a shape and a collapsed (the * next to the comp) pre-comp with text.
[Collapse comp button *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dznrP.png)
In my main comp, I want to keep the TEXT layer in the center whenever I change the text in the text layer.
I can use an expression for that but then it will count the real center, not the center after collapsing the comp?!

//The text in the TEXT comp can not be centered because I edit each part alone. 216 is right-aligned text and 90 i left-aligned.

[Main comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekeTB.jpg)

[Text comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOlk7.png)

I wonder if I can find an expression that count the anchor point for collapsed pre-comps.